# Disable Spatial Navigation

Tags: html, css, opera, smart-tv

I develop smart tv project on Opera TV. Can I disable spatial navigation in my project? Because I create method for control app by javascript and when I navigate app, my method in JS and spatial navigation work both. How can I do this?

Comment: are you using .net or any other language

Comment: @Gagu Oh! I'm sorry. I'm use javascript (base on AngularJS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you rely on own key navigation, you shloud prevent default keydown action of browser.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
  //your navigation code (VK_LEFT, VK_RIGHT, VK_UP, VK_DOWN...)
}, useCapture);
```

Preventing default spatial navigation:
https://dev.opera.com/tv/functional-key-handling-in-opera-tv-store-applications/#prevent-default

Comment: I see this is JavaScript to stop the propagation of the events when the user presses a key. Is that what's needed? How/Why would this solution work?

Comment: https://dev.opera.com/tv/functional-key-handling-in-opera-tv-store-applications/#prevent-default